# Questions regarding INDIRECT function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have the following excel file:[image]

(My Excel is in german, so INDIRECT = INDIREKT)

I have 5 different sheets, named MT, N, S, SW and WE.
I want to combine them and alternatingly put them together, in such a order: 1st row of MT, 1s row of N, ......... 3rd row of MT, 3rd row of N etc.

I already made an index thingy for this in the columns "E" and "F"

Now i want to use the INDIRECT FUNCTION to get the data out of the sheets into the cells.

All 4 sheets contain the same type of rows, so dont worry, they will fit into the columns A-D

This is the one i tried to use but it is not working:

```
=INDIREKT("'" & E2 & "'!" & "A" & WERT(F2) & ":B" & WERT(F2) & ":C" & WERT(F2) & ":D" & WERT(F2))
```

(WERT is german for value)

I honestly have no idea how to get it to work, could somebody help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: put this in a cell: `="'" & E2 & "'!" & "A" & WERT(F2) & ":B" & WERT(F2) & ":C" & WERT(F2) & ":D" & WERT(F2)` and post the result.

Comment: Basically what I am getting at is `'MT'!A1:B1:C1:D1` is not a proper range reference.  Your indirect should be `=INDIREKT("'" & E2 & "'!" & "A" & WERT(F2) & ":D" & WERT(F2))`

Comment: This was the result: 'MT'!A1:B1:C1:D1 when i posted it in, i thought you maybe forgot the INDIREKT, so i put that aswell, but that just throws up an issue with the source.

Comment: As stated that is not a valid reference.  The string that is to be used must resolve to a proper reference or it will fail.

Comment: I think it worked, ill have to try around a bit but you definitely helped me out by a LOT. In case it was able to solve it, i will mark it as done, otherwise i might have to ask you again (:. Again thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0):

@ Scott Craner gave me the answer in the comments. The issue is now solved. Thank you again.